# STM32 HAL_Delay TIMER Microcontroller

Tags: timer, microcontroller, interrupt, hal, stm32f7

What is the difference between HAL_Delay() function and an empty for-loop? Timer should create interrupt and switch off LED.
If I use HAL_Delay() in interrupt function the result is that LED is off forever:

```
void TIM6_DAC_IRQHandler() {
     HAL_TIM_IRQHandler(&htim6);
     HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED1_GPIO_Port, LED1_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
     HAL_Delay(125);        
 }
```

But if I use instead:

```
void  TIM6_DAC_IRQHandler() {
     HAL_TIM_IRQHandler(&htim6); 
     HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED1_GPIO_Port, LED1_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
     for (int i=0; i<1000000; i++);
}
```

then LED1, which is always on in main-file, is set off for short time and then on, as I expect.
So why the code with HAL_Delay does not work?

Comment: empty for loops can get optimized away and if you know how to prevent that the duration of the delay is not as rigid as it used to be on say a PIC.  Even if you tuned it, changing the alignment of the loop can change the time (by adding other code before or nearby) as well as however you solved the optimization can leave it vulnerable.  hardware timers have their own library overhead accuracy issues and you cant delay very small periods, but in general are the better path.

Comment: HAL_Delay() likely relies on the System Timer and SysTick interrupt.  Is the SysTick interrupt enabled?  What is the priority of the SysTick interrupt relative to the TIM6 Interrupt?  If the TIM6 Interrupt is higher priority then the SysTick interrupt will not execute while the TIM6 interrupt is executing and therefore HAL_Delay will not work properly.  Even if the SysTick interrupt is higher priority, delays within interrupt handlers should be avoided so you should rethink your design.

Answer (score 3):

1. The rule of thumb: **NEVER USE DELAYS** in the interrupt handlers.

**`HAL_Delay`** uses SysTick interrupt and if the priority of SysTick is lower than the priority of the interrupt in which handler it is called, will end up in the dead loop as SysTick Handler will be never invoked.

empty loop:
I would personally advice to use another forms of the loops:

```
for(volatile count = 0; count < 1000; count++);
```

or

```
for(count = 0; count < 1000; count++) asm("");
```

https://godbolt.org/z/hY117n